# Display form validation error message on same page using only PHP?

Tags: php, html, validation

I'm very new to PHP and I've cobbled this together from some other answers on here. Can anyone show me how to get the $errMsg to display? At present, a blank or incorrect name leads to a blank page. Is this because the form isn't being displayed again? If so, how should I go about 'reloading' the form with the error message?

```
<?php
$name = "Fred";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

  if (!empty($_POST["name"])) {

      if ($_POST["name"] == $name) {
        include("welcomeFred.php");
      }

      else {
        $errMsg = "Incorrect name";
      }

  }

  else {
    $errMsg = "Name required";
  }

}
else { ?>

  <html>
  ...
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <input type="text" name="name" required>
    <span><?php echo $errMsg;?></span>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  ...
  </html>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: There is no need to put `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>` in the action field of your form. If you leave this blank, the form will be sent to the current url.

Comment: @Jerodev But are there any security issues with the 'blank' approach?

Comment: Not that I can see, anyone could change that value using the html inspector, so if you leave it blank or not, the security will be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't put the rendering of the form in the else of your if structure. This is the reason your form isn't loaded when you submit the form.

Remove the `else { ?>` and `<?php } ?>` at the end of your file and it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you - that makes a lot more sense, it's working now.

Comment: Glad I could help. Consider marking this answer as the solution if this helped you.